# Is there a quick and easy way to associate winzip (or windows built in extractor) with jar files?

Tags: java, windows, winzip

A couple of libraries I'm working with provide "sources", but the sources are actually a series of nested jar files and it's a bit of a pain finding individual files I need to review.

As it stands, I'm renaming the .jar to .zip and opening it up in winzip.  I don't want to extract everything - just locate the one file I want and review it.

I can right-click and choose "open with winzip" on any zip file, or "extract to here" to extract an entire archive to the current directory.

I would like those options to appear for jar files as well, so that I don't have to rename them.

I would still like the primary "open" for jar files to remain the same.

I am working with Windows 7.

Install location is D:\Program Files\WinZip

Comment: Download and install WinRAR. It recognizes `jar` files.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis looks like OP want a Windows way to double click the jar file and letting him to choose the program that will open (AFAIK Android does this for you, not sure if this behavior comes with Windows).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yeah, that's what I thought too. You'll only get those prompts the first time you open an unregistered file type, then the selected option is used as the default. Installing WinRAR adds new options to your right-click that recognizes `jar` and allows you to extract the contained files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click and choose Open With...->Choose Default Program... to open the Open With dialog box.  Choose Winzip from the list (or Browse to it if it isn't listed.)  Be sure to select "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" before clicking ok.  This *will* change your default program settings!

Alternatively, you could create a shorcut to Winzip on your desktop and drag-and-drop files onto it to open them.

You could also add another entry to the context menu by editing the registry.  You can copy the settings from one of the working file types and adapt it for .jar files pretty easily.  The following .reg file should do the trick if you're running 64-bit Windows.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\shell\winzip]
@="Open with WinZip"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\shell\winzip\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\WinZip\\WINZIP64.EXE\" \"%1\""
```

Comment: *I can right-click and choose "open with winzip" on any zip file, or "extract to here" to extract an entire archive to the current directory*

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - The OP says he **can** do that for _.zip_ files but **NOT** for _.jar_ files.

Comment: @jahroy *I would still like the primary "open" for jar files to remain the same.* but this answer will change the default program for jar files. AFAIK WinRAR offers you to unzip JAR files with no problem. Either way, I find this Q/A outside of the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - Got it.  You're right.  And, I agree this is _outside the scope_.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It's not outside the scope of StackOverflow.  It just requires a registry edit.

Comment: @Nilpo care to post the regedit file content then?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I can only guess at it without some more input from the OP.  I need to know the install path for Winzip at the very least.

Comment: Then you don't have an exact answer (compared to the one provided by [Sotirios Delimanolis](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16022783/1065197)).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That's a workaround.  It doesn't solve the OP's problem.  Installing WinRAR won't help him use Winzip at all.

Comment: Let's see: 1. It lets JAR to be opened with the installed JVM as main program but let's you unzip/uncompress the contents. 2. OP can use right click to unzip/uncompress the contents. Looks like an answer for me. Your solution just barely meets with point 2.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Reg file added.

Comment: Thank you!  Your answer reminded me of the old "File Types" dialog that *used* to exist in Windows Explorer.  I couldn't think of the name when I asked the question.  I did find this page that has links to a couple of different file type management utilities. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-to-set-file-associations-in-windows-7-not-open/e3470b2d-385c-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5 but it's not even necessary since you gave me all I needed to know.  THANK YOU.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend installing WinRAR. It adds options when right-clicking a file in Windows. [image].

As you can see, the jar launcher is the default program, but you now have the option to directly extract files. Also, I doubt you need to rename it to `.zip` to open it with WinZip. In binary, it has the correct zip format.

Comment: Can I select two right answers?  Because while this didn't directly answer my question like @Nilpo - this is a great solution.

Comment: @TurtlePowered you can only select one as the answer. Make sure you mark the post that helped you the most.